# Invalid state cookie. An error was encountered while handling the remote login. ASP.NET Core MVC external social login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

While implementing external social login in ASP.NET Core2.2 MVC web application without ASP.NET Core Identity. I am getting below error while redirecting back to the application after successful sign in with Google, Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Microsoft.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   Exception: Invalid state cookie. Unknown location
>
> Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()

[image]

Following are the settings in Startup.cs file

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
       {
           // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
           options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
           options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
       });

       services
           .AddAuthentication(options =>
           {
               options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           })
           .AddCookie(options =>
           {
               options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
           })
           .AddGoogle(options =>
           {
               options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
               options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
               options.CallbackPath = "/externallogincallback";             
           })
           .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
           {
               facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
               facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
               facebookOptions.CallbackPath = "/externallogincallback";                                        
           })
           .AddLinkedIn(linkedinOptions =>
           {
               linkedinOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               linkedinOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:LinkedIn:ClientId"];
               linkedinOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:LinkedIn:ClientSecret"];
               linkedinOptions.CallbackPath = "/externallogincallback";                    
           })
           .AddTwitter(twitterOptions =>
           {
               twitterOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               twitterOptions.ConsumerKey = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerKey"];
               twitterOptions.ConsumerSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerSecret"];
               twitterOptions.CallbackPath = "/Home/externallogincallback";                    
           }).AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
           {
               microsoftOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
               microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
               microsoftOptions.CallbackPath = "/externallogincallback";
           });
       services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
   }
```

Following are the details of HomeController.cs (As I am not using Identity so I need to define redirect url specifically.)

```cs
      //Action to issue a challange to google login
        public IActionResult LogInMicrosoft(string provider)
        {
            //provider = Microsot or Google or LinkedIn or Twitter or Facebook
            provider = "Microsoft";
            //Issue a challenge to external login middleware to trigger sign in process
            //return new ChallengeResult(provider);

            var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action("externallogincallback")
            };

            return Challenge(authenticationProperties, provider);
            //return new ChallengeResult(provider);
        }

        //Callback action to retrive signin user details
        //public IActionResult externallogincallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)\
        public IActionResult externallogincallback()
        {
            //Here we can retrieve the claims
            // read external identity from the temporary cookie
            //var authenticateResult = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie");
            var result = HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            if (result.Result?.Succeeded != true)
            {
                throw new Exception("External authentication error");
            }

            // retrieve claims of the external user
            var externalUser = result.Result.Principal;
            if (externalUser == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("External authentication error");
            }

            // retrieve claims of the external user
            var claims = externalUser.Claims.ToList();

            // try to determine the unique id of the external user - the most common claim type for that are the sub claim and the NameIdentifier
            // depending on the external provider, some other claim type might be used
            //var userIdClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Subject);
            var userIdClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            if (userIdClaim == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unknown userid");
            }

            var externalUserId = userIdClaim.Value;
            var externalProvider = userIdClaim.Issuer;

            // use externalProvider and externalUserId to find your user, or provision a new user

            return RedirectToAction("Privacy", "Home");
        }
```

Comment: @mjwills, I just checked by making `CheckConsentNeeded ` to `false`, but its not working, same error on redirection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you want to redirect the request to `externallogincallback` after sigin the microsoft account. If so, you should not set `microsoftOptions.CallbackPath` with `externallogincallback`. With this setting, all the request from Microsoft will be handled by OAuth Middleware instead of your own endpoint `externallogincallback`.

For redirect page after sign, you need to pass `return Challenge(authenticationProperties, provider);` by setting the `authenticationProperties.authenticationProperties`

Follow steps below:

1. Change the `REDIRECT URI` in Azure portal with `https://localhost:xxx/signin-microsoft`
2. Change `Startup.cs` with

   ```
   public class Startup
   {
       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           Configuration = configuration;
       }

       public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
           {
               // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
               options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
               options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
           });


           services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

           services.AddAuthentication(options =>
               {
                   options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                   //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               })
               .AddCookie(options =>
               {
                   options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                   //options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
               })
               .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
               {
                   microsoftOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                   microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
                   microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];                    
               });
       }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
       {
           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
           }
           else
           {
               app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
               // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
               app.UseHsts();
           }

           app.UseHttpsRedirection();
           app.UseStaticFiles();
           app.UseCookiePolicy();
           app.UseAuthentication();
           app.UseMvc(routes =>
           {
               routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
           });
       }
   }
   ```
3. HomeController

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       //Action to issue a challange to google login
       public IActionResult LogInMicrosoft(string provider)
       {
           //provider = Microsot or Google or LinkedIn or Twitter or Facebook
           provider = "Microsoft";
           var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
           {
               RedirectUri = Url.Action("externallogincallback")
           };
           return Challenge(authenticationProperties, provider);
       }

       [Route("/[action]")]
       public async Task<IActionResult> externallogincallback()
       {
           var request = HttpContext.Request;
           //Here we can retrieve the claims
           // read external identity from the temporary cookie
           //var authenticateResult = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie");
           var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

           if (result.Succeeded != true)
           {
               throw new Exception("External authentication error");
           }

           // retrieve claims of the external user
           var externalUser = result.Principal;
           if (externalUser == null)
           {
               throw new Exception("External authentication error");
           }

           // retrieve claims of the external user
           var claims = externalUser.Claims.ToList();

           // try to determine the unique id of the external user - the most common claim type for that are the sub claim and the NameIdentifier
           // depending on the external provider, some other claim type might be used
           //var userIdClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Subject);
           var userIdClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
           if (userIdClaim == null)
           {
               throw new Exception("Unknown userid");
           }

           var externalUserId = userIdClaim.Value;
           var externalProvider = userIdClaim.Issuer;

           // use externalProvider and externalUserId to find your user, or provision a new user

           return RedirectToAction("Privacy", "Home");
       }
       public IActionResult Index()
       {
           return View();
       }

       public IActionResult Privacy()
       {
           return View();
       }

       [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
       public IActionResult Error()
       {
           return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: IN 1st step "Change the REDIRECT URI in Azure portal with" that you suggest would it be  `https://localhost:xxx/signin-microsoft` or `https://localhost:xxx/externallogincallback`?

Comment: after following the instructions its started redirecting me to following url `https://localhost:44379/signin-microsoft?code=Mcbfea4d8-cd05-b879-51c5-f8ba272b2b62&state=CfDJ8PybjSHN1n9Mh0UWWFFKMATbmTJPJmoqfidOMvb57KUOPTfZ9HsdIlXMWc0KIARYghs9cqWJnm3BS-KzDE7IQYxulIhw6lYSBKq-ZXW72XeeRVMIWUin-azgt1d4e3rXzmXBas9UFY18eTRYTbYN8cIa4bnSacwT6_wnUZyj-JPJAuOcrmFttlv_Ktuxv3JH_rFhqLc11j9xVt4nQcW8gKQ2CnURvnBPZHMQzVbqtrSFJ14L8M2BO0A9sZ3ZaMj8zg`. and giving following error.

Comment: @yadavr You need to add `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseMvc`. Make sure your code is the same as mine.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot, its working fine now. I have another query that i am also using session login to sigining using userid and password, for that I am using  `app.UseSession();` as below. Is it perfectly fine?

`app.UseHttpsRedirection();
 app.UseStaticFiles();
 app.UseCookiePolicy();
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseSession();`